# SQL OR Operator Alternatives

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to select a table called `PRODUCT` with and only display the rows where `V_CODE = 22000` or `55000`.  The problem is that I can't use the `OR` statement for my final answer.  Is there another way to remove the `OR` and get the same result?  See below:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_revised WHERE V_CODE = 22000 OR V_CODE = 55000;
```

Comment: Why can't you use or?

Comment: Just curious, can you give us an explanation as to why you can not use "OR"?

Comment: OR works fine, but I'm just trying to find workarounds for different solutions.  Im just getting started with SQL, so I want to know alternatives to reach the same solution.

Comment: @MartinSmith Whenever I see a question that is essentially no more than "I need to do [x] but I cannot use [the obvious way to accomplish x]" I just assume that it's homework and move on.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `IN` :

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_revised WHERE V_CODE IN(22000, 55000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a mathematical trick:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_revised WHERE (V_CODE - 22000) * (V_CODE - 55000) = 0;
```

Comment: I think you should mention that it works only for Number types and there may be overflow issues with large `V_CODE` values and/or lists with more elements.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred solution is to use `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM PRODUCT_revised
WHERE V_CODE IN (22000, 55000);
```

However, your code should work.

Answer (score 2):

Another way besides `IN` would be to use `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_revised WHERE V_CODE = 22000
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_revised WHERE V_CODE = 55000;
```

or be fancy and use De Morgan laws:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_revised 
WHERE NOT (NOT (V_CODE = 22000) AND NOT (V_CODE = 55000));
```

Comment: Or `SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_revised MINUS SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_revised WHERE V_CODE<>22000 AND V_CODE<>55000`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes of course. I wanted to stress the use of the laws. Your query would show rows with `NULL` in the column. Does Access have `MINUS`?

Comment: I was just playing around with your solution. Access doesn't have MINUS; however, you could use `NOT IN (subselect)`.